# joda.time.DateTime in pojo with hibernate support

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

hibernate - 3.6.0.Final
joda - 1.4
how to support direct joda.DateTime in pojo for hibernate

so can be `session.saveOrUpdate(rateCodeId);`

pojo

```
public class RateCodeId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int roomId;
    private org.joda.Time.DateTime date;
}
```

hbm.xml

```
 <key-property name="date" type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime">
        <column length="10" name="date" />
 </key-property>
```

ERROR:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could
>   not determine type for:
>   org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime

AND without "type=" 
ERROR

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.joda.time.DateTime cannot be cast
>   to java.util.Date

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have [Joda-Time Hibernate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html) in the classpath. It's needed for `type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime"`.

**UPDATE:**

It appears that Joda-time Hibernate support currently doesn't work with Hibernate 3.6, see [PersistentDateTime doesn't work in hibernate 3.6 - ID: 3090209](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html) and [Recompile Joda-Time Hibernate to make it work with Hibernate 3.6](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=AANLkTin%3D2Jwym8NXQGQzy6PrXLjjebtaov8s1NX3dPYF%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=joda-interest).

You can use [User Type project](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/) instead (type attribute becomes `type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime"`).

Comment: oh thanx for reply joda provides. two jar joda-time-hibernate-1.2.jar and joda-time-1.6.2.jar so need to add this one also because "org.joda.time.contrib.." is in hibernate-1.2.jar

Comment: session.createQuery("from RateCode rr where rr.id.date>=:from).setDate/setTimeStamp("from", from) where from in mapping file JODA.Timestamp but in .setDate require util.Date `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TIMESTAMP
        at org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet(PersistentDateTime.java:83)` so  how to query with setDate. Thanks

Comment: Updating to joda-time-hibernate 1.3 solved this problem here.

Comment: +1 for updating to hibernate 1.3 which was released after this answer was posted.

Comment: joda-time-hibernate 1.3 saved my day!